# How do I get to Oracle schema other than my own

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I am in an environment that uses Oracle as the primary data persistence engine, but the data that I need to get to is in multiple schema that I have access to (Read-Only), but do not own. My SQL Developer install was done multiple times, and now I have to try all of them each time I Re-boot my machine.

Using Visual Studio with Oracle data client extension, I can connect to the database server (via IP Address in an .ora file) that I want, but I can't see the schemas that I need.

Any suggestions on how I can either persist the connection using Visual Studio (2019/2022), or make sure the SQL Developer Connection is the right one on Re-boot??

Comment: Without proxy authentication (rarely used) you can't get in as an account that's not yours (that you don't know the password to). That shouldn't stop you from seeing tables owned by others though - simply prefix the table name with the schema name and ensure that your DBA has given you select privs on them. This is the normal way we work with multiple schemas, not trying to connect as each one. Not sure why you would have multiple SQL Developer installs to solve this problem...

Comment: You may issue `alter session set current_schema = whatever` to permanently change default schema for a session. Otherwise you may prefix every object name with it's schema. Or publish them in your own schema with `create synonym objectname for target.objectname` (assuming you have this privilege). All the above will work if you have `select` privilege on the object (or `select any table` system privilege)

Comment: @PaulW, the multiple installs was entirely my own doing in an effort to understand the transition between Windows and Linux. I do understand the basic premise behind different schema for different reasons, just have never used the Oracle implementation through VS (I'm used to VS/SQL Server where you see the db and the associated schema, not the schema and no DB